# Not able to write in file

Tags: java

Am reading one .gzip file content and doing some calculation after reading that content. Now the problem is am not able to write content to a file. my code is as below...

```
public static void  readAndWrite(File fileName, File outputFilePaht) throws Exception {

        GZIPInputStream gzip = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        if(!outputFilePaht.exists()){
            outputFilePaht.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFilePaht,true);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzip));
        try{

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                if(line.contains("Someservername")){
                    bufferedWriter.write(line);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            fileReader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally{
            if(fileWriter!=null)
                fileWriter.close();
        }

    }
```

Am i doing any thing wrong? please suggest me here. am not able to write anything to a file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this string correct? `if(line.contains("Someservername"))`?. Check the case. Also try writing without this condition, just to see where the problem lies

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can _read_ data from the file(s)? Also, are you getting some kind of exception, or is it just that nothing is being written?

Comment: Side note: Consider to use the NIO.2 File API and the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: yes... in system.out.println() method it is printing the  matched line... but the line is not going into file. only blank file is coming

Comment: You are not closing the buffered wirter, may be the cause.

Comment: i tried by closing bufferedwriter also

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (untested):

```
public static void readAndWrite(Path srcFilePath, Path outputFilePath) throws Exception {

    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(Files.newInputStream(srcFilePath))));
         BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, 
                 StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("Someservername")) {
                bufferedWriter.write(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

The try-with-resources statement will close the streams correctly for you.